# Is it mandatory to install rabbit mq to work with Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2

Is it mandatory to install rabbit mq if we are using magneto 2.3.2 or else without rabbit mq also will magento works with all scenarios

Answer (score 1):

You can go without it, the database will be used for messaging if there is no Rabbit involved.